# VSCODE how to preserve, save folding state

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using VSCODE 1.58.2. I am working on large HTML files and I need folding functionality so that it is easy to navigate inside a HTLM page. However, when I close HTML file and then re open it again, my previous folding no longer exist and I have to do the folding again. Please advice me how on how to get the folding functionality to VSCODE. I have no plugins installed on VSCODE and I have set the folding strategy to indentation.

Comment: I also would like to preserve the folding state between sessions.